# nextRowset() do-while loop causing 500 error

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, data-objects

I'm creating a web service for a mobile application in PHP using PDO database calls. The problem code is below:

```
// Prepare Stored Procedure Call
    $query = "CALL " . $_GET['proc'] . '('.implode(', ', array_keys($paramArray)).')';
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($paramArray);
    $resultSets = array();

// Loop And Build Results into a JSON Array

    do {
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($rows){
            //echo json_encode($rows);
            $resultSets[] = $rows;
        }

    } while ($stmt->nextRowset());

    echo "Hello test.";
    echo json_encode($resultSets);
```

The **while ($stmt->nextRowset());** is causing a 500 error on my server, stopping the code.

- With the code above, I get a 500 error, I'm not getting the "Hello test." echo to print, and I'm getting no JSON result set and my connection doesn't close.
- If I remove the do while loop, no 500 error, I get the first row of my result
  (because it's not looping) set and the "Hello test" echo with
  connection close.
- If I place the **echo json_encode($resultSets);** inside of the loop, I get the JSON result set, but I get the first result set in it's entirety, and then I get the first and also the second in their entirety (essentially returning each row as it loops into the result set.  This was predictable, but the loop IS working..).

In every other PDO example I've looked at, this is the loop they use to return data.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Usually a 500 error means a php error, consider checking in your apache error logs in order to see the error. BTW, If you're already using `paramArray` in the query itself, what's the point of `execute($paramArray)` ? (Or maybe i'm missing here something)

Comment: Which version of PHP and Mysql are you using? Please edit your question with the details.